# Docusign authentication without consent prompt/permission to each user of application for Email delivery

Tags: c#, docusignapi, asp.net-core-2.1, e-signature

I am trying to achieve document signing using `email delivery` for an `web application`. But I don't wanted each user to see consent/permission prompt from `docusign`. Simply, user should able to click send document for `esignature` to `docusign` and should get response without leaving application.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! PLEASE check/accept the best answer to each of your questions.

Comment: You'd have to use the Admin Consent feature: https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent/obtaining-admin-consent-internal/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Kaishu you can use JWT flow to achieve this. You can read more here https://developers.docusign.com/docs/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token/
code example https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp/tree/master/launcher-csharp